# how to grep the file names based on the date formate

Tags: shell-script

We have hourly and daily files in the same folder:

```
data-2015-06-06-00.tsv
data-2015-06-06-01.tsv
data-2015-06-06-02.tsv
data-2015-06-06-03.tsv
data-2015-06-06.tsv
data-2015-06-07-03.tsv
data-2015-06-07-02.tsv
data-2015-06-07.tsv
```

How to get the only daily from the list of files.

i need only data-2015-06-06.tsv
data-2015-06-07.tsv

Comment: `ls data-????-??-??.tsv`, since `?` is a wildcard matching any single character.

Comment: But i'm getting the hourly files also for this command. I need only daily files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three more options:

```
ls  | grep ^data-...........tsv
```

or:

```
ls  | grep ^data-"[[:digit:]]\{4\}-[[:digit:]]\{2\}-[[:digit:]]\{2\}.tsv"
```

or:

```
ls  | grep ^data-[1-2][0-1][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-1][0-9].tsv
```

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls, you can replace `ls | grep ^FOO` by `ls FOO` in most case (expect dot), where FOO is above regexp.

Answer (score 3):

today's :

```
 ls date-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)*
```

yesterday's :

```
 ls date-$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d yesterday )*
```

where

- `date +%Y-%m-%d` will format date
- `-d yesterday` use yesterday's date
- `$( )` construct, run command and use output as a string

I assume you can't relay on files last modification times.

Edit:

to avoid hourly from today:

```
 ls date-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tsv
```

to get only daily use @lcd047 's answer.